# Force `this` pointer in C++ with Rider or .editorconfig?

Tags: c++, rider, editorconfig

Is there a way to force the use of the `this` pointer in C++ code with Rider or .editorconfig?

Example:

```cpp
class Foo {
 public:
  void Bar() {
    this->_x++; // forcing the `this->`
  }

 private:
  int _x = 1;
};
```

I want to force the IDE to use the `this` pointer in class properties.

Comment: Why? Why would you want to enforce writing extra unnecessary symbols in your source file? Writing `this->` is usually redundant and - in my experience - most professional developers see this as pointless. Enforcing this seems silly to me.

Comment: Personally I find it cleaner and more readable, easier to identify a class property. In fact, it's more personal taste.

Comment: Just a note about terminology: `this` is not a qualifier, it is a pointer. That's why you have to write either `this->_x` or `(*this)._x` to access the `_x` member variable through `this`. Qualifiers are such keywords as `const` and `volatile` type qualifiers, and lvalue/rvalue ref-qualifiers (the `&` or `&&` tokens that can appear after parameters list in non-static member function declarations).